# Are there any software or libraries(in some language) which draws all the planar graphs given the number of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, math-software, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

I am working on interrelationships between planar and Hamiltonian graphs and for the purpose I need planar graphs for inspection. Since their number grows asymptotically, I cannot approach it manually.

I have searched a lot but could not find any helpful resource(probably because it does not exist). If I have such tool, it would greatly simplify my work and allow me to focus on the actual job rather than drawing the graphs(which is of course impossible if I am working on say 15 vertices).

Please help me out and suggest some software/library which can either directly or indirectly be of use.[It would be an added benefit if the software allows me to check for Hamiltonian-ness of graphs, though it is not my prime concern.]

Thanks!

Comment: plantri (https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) might be helpful for generating certain classes of planar graph, although you would need some other library for drawing them

Comment: There are 23833988129 15 vertex polyhedral graphs.  You can use plantri, as mentioned.  The number of 13-node planar graphs is unknown. 333312451 12-node planar graphs.  Many places have libraries of the more interesting graphs, but no-one keeps a library of the 107854282197058 18-vertex graphs.  Be more specific in your request, or plow through the plantri lists.

Comment: Agree with @EdPegg here - there are a lot of these graphs. Even Hamiltonian ones (https://oeis.org/A003216/list) - perhaps you could sample them at random?